# Dual boot two Windows 7 installations - became single boot after re-installing one

Tags: windows-7

I had two Windows 7 instanced installed on two different partitions. It was dual boot but after format the Windows 7 on partition C: it became single boot and the Windows on partition D: cannot be booted.

Comment: one more thing I have installed the two windows on one hard drive HDD but in different partitions

Comment: Please use the *Edit* button to add more information in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootloader configuration was overwritten. You can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to re-add second instance of Windows.

[image: Step-by-step EasyBCD guide]